# react native reselect state is undefined

Tags: react-native, redux, expo, reselect

why I get this error:

undefined is not an object. state.shopping_cart

reselect

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const carts = state => state.shopping_cart.cart;

export const allCarts = createSelector(
  carts,
  (data) => data
);
```

cart:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import _ from 'lodash';

const shopping_cart = createSlice({
    name: 'shopping_cart',
    initialState: {
      cart: []
    },
....
});

export const { addCart, removeCart, removeCartByProductID, addAmountOnCartItem } = shopping_cart.actions;
export default shopping_cart.reducer;
```

I called like this:

allCarts();

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the state to the selector `allCarts(state);`

You can access the state via:

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

const selectedData = useSelector(state => state);
```

Comment: but where I get state ?

Comment: That depends on whether you are in a component or not, or if you are using hooks.
To answer your question regarding how to access the state ich just need more information.


1. You wanna access the state in a component?

2. Do you use hooks?

3. How do you provide the store?

Comment: I use it with hooks and yes I wanna access the state in a component